# Immutability and Graphs Models - How to create them?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, architecture, immutability

I will use example as its easier to show what I want to do. I have three classes X, Y and Z, and I would like to be able to have them as immutable objects. Here they are.

Class X :

```
public class X{
    private int id;
    private String dataX;

    private Collection<Y> collectionOfY;
    private Collection<Z> collectionOfZ;

    /* Constructors */
    /* Getters */
    /* "with" functions */

}
```

Class Y :

```
public class Y{

    private int id;
    private String dataY;

    private Collection<X> collectionOfX;
    private Collection<Z> collectionOfZ;

    /* Constructors */
    /* Getters */
    /* "with" functions */

}
```

Class Z :

```
public class Z{

    private int id;
    private String dataZ;

    private Collection<X> collectionOfX;
    private Collection<Y> collectionOfY;

    /* Constructors */
    /* Getters */
    /* "with" functions */

}
```

So they are linked with each other and form a graph with a cyclic structure. I would like to have immutable object if possible. I've implemented "With" functions which will send back a copy of a given object with just one property changed.

But, if I implement a total immutability, I will possibly cause a replication of every data linked (directly or indirectly) to the object I changed :
Changing "dataZ" usually means that I want to replace the old object by the newly created one in linked X and Y. Which will be replicated due to the change, etc ...

Another solution would be to render Collections which link the three classes not immutable (and only have a partial immutability) but then I lost almost all interest of trying to have immutability.

Anyone have a good idea ? Or am I asking for the impossible ? Should I return to the old setter (even if it means more complex concurrency management) ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: so you wanna that no body can't modify the objects? or can be create but impossible to modify attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# is able to get around this with its built-in `Lazy<T>`. A `Lazy` is an object whose actual value has not yet been computed - when you construct a `Lazy`, you pass a factory function as a parameter.

You can ask a `Lazy` for its value with the `Value` property. If the factory function has already run, then the already-constructed value is returned. If the factory function hasn't run, then it will run at this time. Whatever the case, the return of the `Value` property is always the same. Once a particular `Lazy`'s value has been determined, it sticks.

A lazy is an immutable reference to a possibly-not-yet constructed object. It uses mutability internally, but from the outside, it appears to be immutable.

In your case, if you had a Java equivalent to `Lazy`, you would change your collections from, say, `Collection<Y>` to `Collection<Lazy<Y>>`. This would enable an instance of X to refer to some not-yet-constructed instances of Y. And the code which constructs the `X`s, `Y`s, and `Z`s would not directly build those instances, but would instead build instances of `Lazy`. These instances would take factory functions as parameters; these factory functions, in turn, would need to reference to some of the `Lazy` values. This means that, within the context of the function that's constructing and wiring these things together, you'll need to have mutable references to Lazy instances.

To see what I mean, if you try to create a cycle of two objects (I'm not completely up on Java 8, so I might have syntax errors):

```
Lazy<X> a;
Lazy<Y> b;

a = new Lazy<X>(() -> {
    List<Y> ys = new ArrayList<Y>();
    ys.add(b.getValue());
    return new X(ys);
});

b = new Lazy<Y>(() -> {
    List<X> xs = new ArrayList<X>();
    xs.add(a.getValue());
    return new Y(xs);
});
```

In practice, I don't think that will work. I think closed-over variables need to be final in Java (this isn't the case in C#). So I think you'd need to actually do this:

```
final Lazy<X>[] a = new Lazy<X>[1];
final Lazy<Y>[] b = new Lazy<Y>[1];

a[0] = new Lazy<X>(() -> {
    List<Y> ys = new ArrayList<Y>();
    ys.add(b[0].getValue());
    return new X(ys);
});

b[0] = new Lazy<Y>(() -> {
    List<X> xs = new ArrayList<X>();
    xs.add(a[0].getValue());
    return new Y(xs);
});
```

This works because the two lambdas aren't evaluated immediately. As long as `a[0]` and `b[0]` get set to valid values before these lambdas are executed, everything will work fine.

Note that this uses mutability, but mutability in very limited scopes. There's mutability inside the `Lazy` instances, but these instances appear to be immutable. There's mutability in the wire-up function, but that function will run up front and terminate, whereas the constructed objects can live for much longer. This constrained mutability is, at least for me, an acceptable tradeoff.